# Realm.io RLMException on commitWriteTransaction - Index out of bounds

Tags: ios, realm

I've been using the following code successfully, and all of a sudden, for one of my models, Realm throws an index out of bounds error on `commitWriteTransaction`. The Realm objects are successfully created, and it's only on the final line below that the error appears, and it only happens for one of my models. I did update the server return recently, but the model still appears correct as it successfully creates an object from the server data (model shown below).

Btw I need to delete and reinstall the app every time it crashes. If I try to open it again, it'll crash before getting anywhere (I'm assuming that's because the DB is messed up).

What's going on? And how do I fix this?

**Code:**

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = (NSDictionary *)responseObject; //response from AFNetworking call to my server
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
for (NSDictionary *dict in responseDictionary){
    MyModel *object = [[class alloc] initMyModelWithDictionary:dict]; //class is known
    // (print object) - see output below
    [realm addOrUpdateObject:object];
}
[realm commitWriteTransaction]; // Error thrown here
```

**Model printout example (one of the ones from `dict`)**

```
MyModel {
    id = 32;
    created_at = 2016-07-02 03:39:15 +0000;
    updated_at = 2016-07-02 03:39:15 +0000;
    intA = 1;
    intB = 2;
    intC = 0;
    boolA = 1;
    boolB = 1;
    boolC = 1;
    boolD = 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', 
reason: 'Index 0 is out of bounds (must be less than 0)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception is only thrown when either a `RLMArray`, `RLMLinkingObjects`, or `RLMResults` has an out-of-bounds access. Given that index 0 is out of bounds, it must be empty when the 0th index is accessed. Realm isn't itself accessing this collection when you call `commitWriteTransaction`. Instead, it is delivering a notification to your code that is performing the out-of-bounds access. You should be able to easily find out where this is occurring by turning on exception breakpoints.